# DevExpress Pivot Grid not accepting format string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

I have a DevExpress PivotGrid in my site that grabs a bunch of numbers from a sql view. I'd like to format them to 2 decimal places. I've tried the following:

```
<dx:pivotgridfield id="AverageDailySales" visible="True"
 fieldname="AvgDailySales" CellFormat-FormatString="(0:n2}" Options-AllowFilter="True"></dx:pivotgridfield>
```

And in the page_load:

```
AverageDailySales.CellFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.Numeric
AverageDailySales.CellFormat.FormatString = "{0:n2}"
AverageDailySales.GrandTotalCellFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.Numeric
AverageDailySales.GrandTotalCellFormat.FormatString = "{0:n2}"
```

But it's still not formatting to two places. When I put it as a data field (and I get a grand total column for it), it works. Otherwise it doesn't. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just an observation. You have `CellFormat-FormatString="(0:n2}"`. There's a '(' instead of a '{' there. Shouldn't it be `{0:n2}"`?

Comment: Probably so -- I hadn't noticed that until now. I inherited this project and there's a pretty sizable amount of crappy code, so sometimes stuff like that sort of blends in.

Comment: @shamp00 forgot to tag ya in the first one and I can't edit it. So tagging you now in case for some reason you were interested

Answer (score 1):

I believe your format string is incorrect, it should not include the 0 identifier. This should be:

```
<dx:pivotgridfield id="AverageDailySales" visible="True"
 fieldname="AvgDailySales" CellFormat-FormatString="n2" Options-AllowFilter="True"></dx:pivotgridfield>
```

Typically the format fields in DevExpress look just for the format to use, and assume there is only a single value to format. I'm also basing this on the DevExpress [How to: Format Cells](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument7240) documentation.